# Batch for creating a txt file with the filename for each file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say I have a folder with a bunch of files with .dat extension. I would like to write a batch that, for each .dat file in the folder, would create a corresponding .txt file. Each .txt should contain the filename of its .dat counterpart inside it, as well as in its own filename. So if I have:

123.dat
ABC.dat
zyx.dat

The batch file should create the fillowing files:
123.txt, containing the text "123.dat"
ABC.txt, containing the text "ABC.dat"
zyx.txt, containing the text "zyx.dat"

How can I do this? I've tried using the following line:

> for %%x in (*.dat) do type %%x > %%~nx.txt

As well as this one:

> for %%f in (*.dat) do type %%f > %%f.txt

Both generate a .txt file for each .dat file, but they copy the content of the corresponding .dat file to the .txt, rather than writing its filename in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didnt test it but this should work.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.dat') do (
  echo %%~nxa>%%~na.txt
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

in poweshell:

```
dir *.dat | %{set-content -value $_.name -path ($_.basename + ".txt")}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my coding for my project, it should work on your computer, it create thing that you want to say from batch to txt

@echo off
color 0a
:pro4
cls
echo please type in your word
set /p word1=
goto saving

:saving
echo %word1% > project.txt

Comment: Please consider using _**Stackoverflow Formatting Markups**_.